# Load-time weaving (AspectJ): Hystrix breaks transaction propagation

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aspectj, hystrix

I'm having a problem with a combination of `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` with AspectJ + `@Transactional` + `@HystrixCommand`.

So, I've configured load-time weaving like this:

```
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = ENABLED)
@EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

plus instrumentation configuration.

I have a bean A, annotated with `@Transactional` and method in it, annotated with `@HystrixCommand`.

Then I have a bean B, also annotated with `@Transactional`, but having `propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY`, which means that it requires existing transaction and fails otherwise. There's also a method in this bean, annotated with `@HystrixCommand`.

Eventually, when I call the method of bean B from the method of bean A, I get: `No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'`.

I was looking for the problem for a couple of hours: everything seems to be configured properly, so I almost gave up. And then I just tried to remove `@HystrixCommand` from methods. And voilà: transaction propagation started to work properly and the exception was gone.

So I wonder: why does `@HystrixCommand` break transaction propagation? Is it somehow related to the fact that I'm using load-time weaving? Or is it expected behaviour? Can someone shed some light on it?

Comment: I am kind of an AspectJ expert, but a Spring noob and have no idea what Hystrix is. Maybe a few more pairs of eyes would help, but for that an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would be necessary, I am afraid. You explanation is good and probably correct, but I cannot build, run and debug it.... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was about to start drafting MCVE when Michiel answered and it was the case: Spring's `@Transactional` doesn't support multithreading, which is brought by `@HystrixCommand`. So there's nothing to do with weaving or AspectJ here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're stating is probably related to the fact that `HystrixCommands` are executed in an isolated [thread](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#executionisolationstrategy):

> The default, and the recommended setting, is to run HystrixCommands using thread isolation (THREAD) and HystrixObservableCommands using semaphore isolation (SEMAPHORE).
>
> Commands executed in threads have an extra layer of protection against latencies beyond what network timeouts can offer.
>
> Generally the only time you should use semaphore isolation for HystrixCommands is when the call is so high volume (hundreds per second, per instance) that the overhead of separate threads is too high; this typically only applies to non-network calls.

Comment: This... makes a lot of sense. Thank you!